# Mom Got Me Shoes For My Birthday

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

What number must replace the question mark below?

218
19
780
17
11
9,000
301
6
8
600
**?**
80
70

Comment: The title is not a direct clue. It is mainly for confirmation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The number is

> 1

as this sequences encodes

> 218 - **T**wo **H**undred **E**ighteen
>  19  - **N**ineteen
>  780 - **S**even **H**undred **E**ighty
>  17 - **S**eventeen
>  11 - **E**leven
>  9,000 - **N**ine **T**housand
>  301 - **T**hree **H**undred **O**ne
>  6 - **S**ix
>  8 - **E**ight
>  600 - **S**ix **H**undred
>  **?**
>  80 - **E**ighty
>  70 - **S**eventy

so we find a number which will fit

> THEN SHE SENT THOSE SH?ES

Comment: I'm feeling dumb, but I don't get the answer. Can you maybe explain your reasoning? What does spelling out the numbers do here? EDIT: I got it now, but it might be worth telling explicitly how you got that bottom sentence

Comment: @Ivo Added in bold for the letters that are used